# Using capacitive touch switch as guitar pick-up selector

Tags: switches, capacitive

I want to use two Schurter 3-101-401 one for each pick up.

I was able to get them wired up but the signal for the pick-ups comes out no matter what.

Here is the info https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/693-3-101-401

I basically want to connect the pick-up output to this switch then the output of this switch to a volume potentiometer. However it looks like there is a positive and negative wire for power and two output wires. What gives? How do I wire this up? I am a noob and need help desperately.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEsJyk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please add a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea - Your switches have MOS-based outputs, it will MAYBE work with pick-up signals (around tens to several hundred mV for humbuckers) but certainly it will change the character of sound.

Comment: Unless you understand EMI well, with common mode noise rejection  from hum RF etc in air and strings and pickup your signals need to be “well protected.” With shielded pairs , decoupling caps and low impedance with ESD protection. Not for newbies sorry. Bad idea because pro guitarists want a dial or switch they can flick in a 1/16th beat and not skip a note or make an error in setting.@&%#

Comment: Spot on. Even if you were able to make this work, you would have turned the guitar into a gadget. A guitar is not supposed to be a gadget, it's supposed to be a tool, so use a proper switch and Keep It Simple. Ok, to be fair, if the guitar is yours, then that's for you to decide... but if you do decide that it should be a gadget, you would still be wrong. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thats a really cool switch, the datasheet, not so cool.

It appears that they have a microcontoller in the switch (I am not 100% sure), it toggles two 
wires called out1 and out2. Information on how it toggles the lines is not information that is available because this datasheet is horrible.

The only information given is out1 and out2 are most likely conntected to an optomos relay, if the optmos is between ground and out1, or out1 and out2 is not described in this crappy datasheet.

I'd get a meter and ohm it out and complain to the company.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I read that drawing, OUT1 and OUT2 are connected to each other when the switch is closed - no connection to ground.  Trying to pass pickup-level signals through an optoMOS switch is probably not a good idea...  To the OP: this is not a "real' mechanical switch - it is a semiconductor device.

Comment: That's one way to interpret it, and would be the most logical way, but there is no way to know for sure. There is also no information in the datasheet about how much current that optomos can take

Comment: So it’s not possible with these switches ?

Comment: Could I use like a ttp223 cap sensor with the output going to a transistor that would close and allow the pick up Signal to pass from one side to the other?

Comment: Connect a voltage to wire 1 (5 to 28V, take your pick, how about a 9v battery?) then place a meter across out1 and out2 and measure the conductivity while actuating the switch, if you like the answer upvote